# DOC TO XPS FILE DOCUMENT

Tags: vb.net, document, xps

I just wanted to know how can I convert my document .doc path to xps file document.

If anyone can help I would be glad to know the code in VB.NET since I googled it already but unfortunately I can't find best answer to my question.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I did this using the following code in a console application.
You'll need to reference the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly (version 12 on later for the ability to generate XPS files) and import the namespace.

The code in VB is:

```
Option Explicit On

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim word As _Application
    Dim doc As _Document

    word = New Application
    doc = word.Documents.Open("C:\test.doc")
    doc.SaveAs("C:\test.xps", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS)
    word.Quit()
End Sub

End Module
```

And in C#:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _Application word = new Application();
            _Document doc = word.Documents.Open(@"C:\test.doc");
            doc.SaveAs(@"C:\test.xps", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
            word.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```